# Wordpress custom wp-cron class doesn't firing the scheduled handler

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

So, we use the Bedrock to help to code our products and I need to build a generic class to handle custom cronjobs.

This is the base cronjob class:

```
<?php
namespace namespace\to\the\class;

abstract class CronHelper extends AbstractHelper {

    /** Declare all attributes and other methods */

    /**
     * Setup the custom cronjob
     */
    protected function init() {
        $this->setAlias(DEFAULT_CRON_ALIAS);
        $this->setInterval(DEFAULT_CRON_INTERVAL);
        $this->setDisplay(DEFAULT_CRON_DISPLAY);
    }

    /**
     * Start the cronjob
     */
    public function start() {
        add_filter('cron_schedules', array($this,'customInterval'));
        add_action($this->getAlias(), array($this,'runner'));

        if (! wp_next_scheduled($this->getAlias())) {
            wp_schedule_event(time(), "{$this->getAlias()}_interval", $this->getAlias());
        }
    }

    /**
     * The custom interval builder
     *
     * @return array The custom interval setup
     */
    public function customInterval() {
        $scheduler["{$this->getAlias()}_interval"] = array('interval' => $this->getInterval(),'display' => $this->getDisplay());
        return $scheduler;
    }

    /**
     * The scheduler implementation function
     */
    protected abstract function runner();
}
```

What you guys should know:

- AbstractHelper is a Singleton class
- I suppressed the getters/setters
- The method `start()` is fired on every page load of our site

This is one implementation of the CronHelper class:

```
<?php
namespace namespace\to\the\class;

class TestCron extends CronHelper {

    protected function runner() {
        // Try to print something on the nginx's error logs
        error_log('Running inside the class TestCron');
        // Create a random file just for testing
        $file = fopen('./cronjob.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($file, sprintf('Hello World [%d]', time()));
        fclose($file);
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm instantiating everything, remember this piece of code is executed every time:

```
<?php
/** A lot of code above ... */

// Start the Test Cronjob
TestCron::getInstance()->setAlias('test_cron')
    ->setDisplay('Test Cronjob')
    ->setInterval(5) // Fire every 5 seconds
    ->start();

/** A lot of code below ... */
```

And every time I load the page and navigate through the site nothing happens. I was wondering what am I doing wrong?!

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I finally discover what was going on with my code. And I just let it here for future similar doubts.

The solution is: instead of using a `protected` method, use a `public` method for your `runner()` wannabe function.